# Stop at Waiting for device. Target device: samsung-XXXXX

Tags: android, gradle

I use Intellij and Gradle build android project, when I run the project that stop at 
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-xxxx.

How do I solve?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellij update to version 14.0.2, the problem can solver.